# "Cannot import name genshi" error when installing the Swab library

Tags: installation, python

I'm trying to install the Swab library for Python 2.6 in Ubuntu 10.10.

However, I get the following error messages when I try to import it.

In the terminal I ran:

```
sudo easy_install swab
sudo easy_install Genshi
```

In the Python interpreter I ran:

```
>>> import swab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/swab-0.1.2-py2.6.egg/swab/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pestotools.genshi import genshi, render_docstring
ImportError: cannot import name genshi
```

I don't know whats going on. can anyone help.

Comment: It's worth seeing if the right files are there. What do you get for the following? "cd /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ && find -name pestotools* -print"

Answer (score 1):

I've run `sudo easy_install swab` in Ubuntu 10.10 and got all dependencies installed (no need to run `sudo easy_install Genshi` separately).

Unfortunately, when I look at pestotools module (installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pestotools.genshi-0.2.3.py2.6.egg/pestotools/genshi/__init__.py` in my system), I don't see any `genshy` or `render_docstring`.

This means that `swab` package is assuming that those symbols are present in `pestotools.genshi` namespace when they're not. I'd say that both packages went out of sync and that maybe some older version of `pestotools.genshi` still works fine together with `swab`. Anyway, the best way to make sure is to contact `swab` maintainer.